Crazy Games rejected my game and after carefully going through their quality guidelines and doing some playtesting I am stumped
I am aware that my game is far from a masterpiece and is very simple. I wanted to make a simple game that will be easy to jump in and out of and has as few controls and UI as possible. I see that as good web game criteria. That is why I decided to make a simple top-down shooter where the player controls only the movement and everything else depends on movement. For example, the gun always shoots the closest enemy(targeting = movement), enemies will combine into a stronger enemy if they touch so the player should try and move in a way that wouldn't cause that. The two abilities are also centered around helping with movement. The game has a few guns that can be upgraded. The player can also be upgraded. In the end the player becomes a bit OP, which I find satisfying. So I submitted my  game to Crazy Games, but it got rejected. They did not provide any feedback and also don't answer any questions related to feedback. Because of that I would really appreciate it if any of you who might have any thoughts or related experiences can share them with me, as I am out of ideas. I worked on the game for quite some time and would like to get it on there. This is a link to the game, I am not putting it here in order to promote the game, I am putting it here in case playing might  help with any suggestions you might  have.
Thank you in advance,
Spas.

The other question is for a different game, but I think they share the same problem: the games in question are prototypes & not yet ready for release. The lack of background makes movement disorienting / hard to read. Your core idea about movement vs aiming isn't mentioned in the game tutorial & going in 'blind' the gameplay doesn't last long enough to figure that out organically. I recommend getting some playtest feedback & iterating.

You may want to try posting on playtesting communities like r/playmygame instead (Just make sure to check their posting guidelines first). We don't review games and give open-ended feedback on this particular Q&A site.
